# Restore Subversion respository which was reverted by a filesystem snapshot

Tags: svn, version-control, recovery

Our IT intern made a boo-boo on our source control server and decided to fix it by reverting the server to a vm snapshot made several hours ago.  He neglected to mention until I informed our IT staff that we were having problems checking out and committing code; apparently it did not occur to him that there would be a problem with reverting the server if we'd been committing code all day.

What's the quickest, safest way to get our revisions back into source control?  Version numbers are all screwed up now, and our CI server has come to a screeching, smoking halt.

Comment: As historical diffs AFAIK aren't stored in svn checkouts, that would be tough. The best thing I can think of is: for every developers checkout, create a new branch on the server. Let the devs checkout that branch. Copy the checkouts they were working on, remove all .svn dirs, replace with the .svn dirs of that branch, and commit to branch. Then, start merging all into the trunk (or specific branches) they were working on. The history won't be the same, some people may commit others code, but actual replay is OTOH not possible, and this way its still mergable. CI needs to be reset to that one.

Comment: Thanks!  If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Before the dust settles, revoke that intern's ability to revert snapshots on mission-critical servers.

Comment: @alroc yah no kidding, not my call though and I'd like to think he learned his lesson; I believe that every technology professional worth anything makes a serious screwup in production... once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't any ways (if you haven't intermediate backups of FS or repository dumps or repo-mirrors)

Because for any CVCS (Subversion is CVCS (Centralized Version Control System)) full repository history stored in single central place, you can't restore killed history from developers Working Copy - you can only have new commits (with *some tricks*) with vanilla revisions of working copies and current state of working copies (if local modifications exist)